# Why the error info can't be recorded into specified file?

Tags: python, scrapy

Platform:debian 8+python 3.4+Scrapy 1.3.2 
Here is my spider to download some urls form yahoo.com

```
import scrapy  
import csv

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):  
    name = "quote"  
    allowed_domains = ["yahoo.com"] 
    start_urls = ['url1','url2','url3',,,,'urls100']

    def parse(self, response):  
        filename = response.url.split("=")[1]  
        open('/tmp/'+filename+'.csv', 'wb').write(response.body)
```

Some error info occurs when to execute it:

```
2017-02-19 21:28:27 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response 
<404 https://chart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GLU>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
```

**https://chart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GLU** is one of start_urls.

Now i want to catch the error info .

```
import scrapy
import csv

import logging
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
configure_logging(install_root_handler=False)
logging.basicConfig(
    filename='/tmp/log.txt',
    format='%(levelname)s: %(message)s',
    level=logging.INFO
)

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quote"
    allowed_domains = ["yahoo.com"]
    start_urls = ['url1','url2','url3',,,,'url100']

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("=")[1]
        open('/tmp/'+filename+'.csv', 'wb').write(response.body)
```

Why the error info such as
**2017-02-19 21:28:27 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response 
    <404 https://chart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GLU>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed** 
can not be recorded in  /home/log.txt?

Think to eLRuLL,i added **handle_httpstatus_list = [404]**.

```
import scrapy
import csv

import logging
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
configure_logging(install_root_handler=False)
logging.basicConfig(
    filename='/home/log.txt',
    format='%(levelname)s: %(message)s',
    level=logging.INFO
)

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [404]
    name = "quote"
    allowed_domains = ["yahoo.com"]
    start_urls = ['url1','url2','url3',,,,'url100']

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("=")[1]
        open('/tmp/'+filename+'.csv', 'wb').write(response.body)
```

The error info still can not be recorded into /home/log.txt file,why?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `handle_httpstatus_list` attribute on your spider to handle `404` statuses:

```
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [404]
```